# How to add a custom css style for specific item in a combo/choice box in JavaFx?

Tags: css, javafx, custom-controls

[image: Screen Capture]

I am using javaFx, and I want to mimic this control. Specificly the link in the bottom of the menu !!
is it possible to do it with css only or without creating a custom control?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement a custom control, but you do need a cell factory to do this. The basic idea is to add a style class to the cell if it requires it, and remove it if not. So you can do, for example:

```
final String cellStyleClass = "my-combo-box-cell" ;

ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
combo.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<String>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        getStyleClass().remove(cellStyleClass);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
            if (/* needs style class */) {
                getStyleClass().add(cellStyleClass);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The test to see if you need to add the style class can obviously reference the `item`, etc.

Now in your CSS file you can style the cell as you need it:

```css
.my-combo-box-cell {
    /* specific styles here... */
}
```